# Postgres Format When Creating a Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas

My work is testing out Postgres.  I usually write in SQL using SAS with Oracle and Teradata syntax.  Our test database has a really sloppy table in which every column was created as a character 255.  I have a very simple thing I'm trying to do but it's not working.  I want to create a new table and reformat from 255 to 10.  I also want to remove all the trailing blanks.  Also, "IS NULL" is not working.  Even when there is nothing visible for a value.

```
PROC SQL;
CONNECT TO POSTGRES(&connectstuff);
EXECUTE(CREATE TABLE common.UNQ_NUM_LIST AS
        SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUE_NUM, 
               BTRIM(PAT_ACCT) AS PAT_ACCT 
        FROM ACCT_DATA.ACCNTS
) by postgres;
DISCONNECT FROM POSTGRES;
QUIT;
```

I want to create PAT_ACCT as a character 10 format but not sure how.  Can I indicate a new format when creating a table? Everything I've tried didn't work.  Even the BTRIM doesn't actually seem to get rid of the trailing spaces on that value either.  And again, null values aren't being recognized with "IS NULL".  I feel like this should be very simple!

Comment: Show us sample data, current and desire output. `Everything I've tried didn't work` what have you tried. What mean doesn't work? Error / Wrong result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To influence the data type, cast the result column in the query appropriately:

```
CAST (btrim(pat_acct) AS character(10)) AS pat_acct
```

There is, however, no way to set a column `NOT NULL` that way.

I recommend that you execute two statements: one that creates the table the way you want it, and another one like

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT ... FROM ...
```

Comment: Awesome!  That did it!  Thank you.